# AVAudioPlayer Swift 3 not playing sound

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I added the AVFoundation.framework to my project. In my project navigator I added the file "Horn.mp3", this is a sound of 1 second.

When a button is pressed (with a image of a horn) the sound should play, also should a label change it's text.

The label is changing it's text, but the sound isn't playing.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func hornButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        playSound()
        hornLabel.text = "Toet!!!"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var hornLabel: UILabel!

    func playSound(){
        var player: AVAudioPlayer?
        let sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Horn", withExtension: "mp3")
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound!)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to step through your playSound() method in the debugger and see what part of it is failing

Comment: I already did that, but every step seems to work. It isn't skipping parts and goes trough the correct lines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to move the `AVPlayer`'s declaration to class-level. `AVPlayer` can't play sounds when you declare them in methods.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer? // <-- notice here

    @IBAction func hornButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        playSound()
        hornLabel.text = "Toet!!!"
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var hornLabel: UILabel!

    func playSound(){
        let sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Horn", withExtension: "mp3")
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound!)
            guard let player = player else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: My teacher said it would be efficiently to put it in my function, but thanks this works.

Comment: Oh, of course. The issue is that you need to keep a strong reference to the audio player. When you use a local variable then the strong reference goes away when the function goes out of scope and the audio player gets released. You could make the audio player an Optional defined as an instance variable. That would solve the weak reference problem.

Comment: I've been programming iOS for like 1900 years and I totally just forgot to do this!  Thanks!

Comment: @Stefan, you can tell your teacher, their idea will only work for ***really short sounds***  :)  :)

Comment: For me, it didn't even work for shorter sounds. Thanks @Sweeper for the answer.