# Ok so I'm new to Swift. I've been trying to make an audio player and the code just gives me this error. What can I do?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class AVAudioPlayer : NSObject {

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

         }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
    func playSound() {
        let player: AVAudioPlayer?
        guard let sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "C", withExtension: "wav") else { return }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, fileTypeHint:   AVFileType.wav.rawValue)

            guard let player = player else { return }

            func play() -> Bool {}

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Xcode gives me an error in this line `player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)` saying that **Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
Replace '(contentsOfURL: sound, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)' with ''** and when I try to fix it, it gives me this error: **Cannot assign value of type 'AVAudioPlayer.Type' to type 'AVAudioPlayer'**. Can somebody help me? PS sorry for bold, Stack wouldn't let me post because it had "too much code in it".

After the help from Sweeper, my code looks like this:

```
import AVFoundation


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    @IBAction func keyPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

         }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}
    func playSound() {
        guard let sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "C", withExtension: "wav") else { return }

        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer

            guard let player = player else { return }

            func play() -> Bool {}

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

As I was saying in the comments, now it gives me this error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'player'`

Comment: Delete your `AVAudioPlayer` class. You shouldn't create your own `AVAudioPlayer` class. After you deleted it, it will be resolved to the correct `AVAudioPlayer` from `AVFoundation`. Also, you are making the mistake I addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42748014/avaudioplayer-swift-3-not-playing-sound/42748072#42748072).

Comment: Thank you! But now it gives me another error smh: now it can't resolve player (```Use of unresolved identifier 'player'```)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `init(contentsOf:) throws` method to initialize the player. Here is the code you need:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVAudioPlayer?

    func playSound() {
        guard let sound = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "C", withExtension: "wav") else { return }
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)
            player?.play()
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```